# Is it possible to set line limitation in the AStyle

Tags: coding-style, formatting, astyle

I am using AStyle to format C or cpp source codes. I am just wondering it is possible to set line limitation in the AStyle?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not, but the author has stated that this will come in a future update.

http://astyle.sourceforge.net/news.html